# Prove that $r(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, trace

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Show that if $A^3=A$, then $r(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A^2)$.

---

Since $A^3=A$, the possible eigenvalues are $0,1,-1$. I don't know from here how to compute the rank of $A$.

**Edited**

Since eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,1,-1$ SO eigenvalues of $A^2=0,1$ So $r(A^2)=tr(A^2)$ Now we have to show $r(A^2)=r(A)$ where rank of $A^2$ is the number of non-zero eigenvalues .

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589182/if-a2-a-then-prove-that-textrmtra-textrmranka). The arguments are the same.

Answer (score 3):

The rank is the number of nonzero eigenvalues and as their squares are 0 or 1, this number is just the same as the sum of the squares.

Comment: but why both equal ??

Comment: @RAM_3R Since every non-zero eigenvalue of $A^2$ is 1, the trace counts exactly the number of non-zero eigenvalues, which is the same as the rank.

Comment: @RAM_3R Because the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues

Comment: This is not correct. The rank of a matrix in general is **not** equal to the number of nonzero eigenvalues (consider e.g. any nontrivial nilpotent block). You need to show that $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: It's the number of non-zero eigenvalues *counted with multiplicity*.

Comment: @Zach Langley then $r(A^2)=tr(A^2)$

Comment: why $r(A)=tr(A^2)$