# how to prove a corollary of multivariate normal??

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Corollary:

If $n \times 1$ vector $y \sim N(0, I)$ and then $n \times n$ matrix A is symmetric and idempotent and of rank $m$. Then $$ y'Ay \sim \chi ^2 (m).$$

How can I prove this corollary?

Comment: I think what you want is the 3d theorem of this: http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/hallam/documents/QUAD_NORM.pdf (has a nice proof in it) you need $A$ to be symmetric

Answer (score 1):

[<s>An idempotent matrix is diagonalizable.</s>](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600745/idempotent-matrix-is-diagonalizable)

---

I think you also need $A$ to be symmetric. If this is the case, the spectral theorem implies we can write $A$ as $BDB^\top$, where $B$ is orthogonal, and where $D$ is diagonal with diagonal entries either $1$ or $0$ (since $A$ is idempotent). Since $A$ has rank $m$, there are $m$ ones.

By rotational invariance of the Gaussian distribution, $z:=B^\top y \sim N(0,I)$ as well. So $y^\top A y = z^\top D z$ is the sum of $m$ squares of standard Gaussian random variables, which is $\chi^2(m)$.

---

I don't think the result holds when $A$ is not symmetric. Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. It is idempotent with rank $m=1$. However, $y^\top A y = y_1^2 - y_1 y_2$ which is not $\chi^2(1)$.