# Diagonalizable matrix and diagonalizable linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The definition of diagonalizable matrix and diagonalizable linear map is given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix and the poof that every idempotent matrix is diagonalizable is given in **Proof 1** here [Idempotent matrix is diagonalizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600745/idempotent-matrix-is-diagonalizable) , but I do not understand how the definition of diagonalizable linear map is used in **Proof 1**, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He doesn't use that definition, but he showed that $A:V\longrightarrow V$ is a diagonalizable linear map. Indeed he found a basis such that the associated linear map is represented by a diagonal matrix.

Comment: he used the definition of a diagonalizable linear map?

Comment: your answer is not clear for me.... please what is the definition of a diagonalizable linear map that he used?

Comment: Yes, a map is diagonalizable if there exists a basis such that the associated matrix is diagonal. He found a basis of eigenvectors for $A$ and then respect to it the matrix id diagonal

Comment: The same given in Wikipedia that you cited above

Comment: a linear map T : V → V is called diagonalizable if there exists an ordered basis of V with respect to which T is represented by a diagonal matrix..... where is the ordered basis that he found? and how he showed that with respect to this basisT is represented by a diagonal matrix?

Comment: He found $r$ linear indipendent eigenvectors of eigenvalue $1$. Precisely he took a basis for the image and then a preimage of such basis, note that these are linearly indipendent. After that he chose a basis of the kernel, they are linearly indipendent and eigenvectors of eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: What is the diagonal matrix that A is represented by?

Comment: Is a diagonal matrix where the first $r$ diagonal entries are $1$ and the remaining $n-r$ diagonal entries are zeros. All non-diagonal entries are zeros as well.